# codeigniter site_url() from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to call my function in controller class from `JavaScript` with the parameter

```
success: function(data) {
    var output = '';
    $("#dropdwn_cari").html(output);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var buku = data[i];
      console.log(buku['value']);

      output += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='<?= site_url('data/buku/" + buku['value'] + "')?>'><a/>";
      $("#dropdwn_cari").html(output);
```

Comment: This is only half of a question. The 2nd half should read... "And here is the generated Source code when I did a Right Click - View Source - from my browser" (with the relevant code in your question).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language it runs before the browser renders your page. You can not pass a value to a PHP function in the way you are trying, because the PHP will consider it as a string i.e `buku['value']`. PHP will not pick the value inside `buku['value']`.
I'm rewriting it for you to try it.

```
success: function(data) {
    var output = '';
    $("#dropdwn_cari").html(output);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var buku = data[i];
      console.log(buku['value']);

      output += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='<?= site_url('data/buku/')?>" + buku['value'] + "'><a/>";
      $("#dropdwn_cari").html(output);
```